# Dual Boot 10.10 and 11.04 can't boot into 10.10 after an update

Tags: 10.10, boot, grub2

I've been dual booting my system with **Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick Meerkat)** and 11.04 **(Natty Narwhal)** but today after an update, **I can't boot into 10.10**, there's only option to boot into 11.04 and **Grub also looks a bit different**.

Before this update, I used to see first option for 11.04 and an other option called `/dev/sda1` for 10.10 but now there is a new option called `Previous Linux Versions`, but when I Enter into that menu, there is `no option to boot into 10.10` all the options take me to 11.04 now it looks like this...
[image]

**And when I click on Previous Linux Versions...[image]**

Comment: Possibly a bug, did you have a look at Launchpad?

Comment: Didn't find anything.

Comment: Does doing a grub update in 11.04 change anything?

Comment: Already tried updating grub but It doesn't detect 10.10 anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First mount the partition on which 10.10 is installed. You can do this by clicking the on the partition in nautilus sidebar.

Once mounted, run this command in the terminal

```
sudo update-grub2
```

Comment: Thanks Owais, It solved my problem. If you have a minute could you explain what could have caused the problem, so I'd be more cautious in future.
Thanks again.

Comment: your update must have consisted of the linux-kernel or some other package which needs updating of grub.cfg and you must have updated white the 10.10 partition was unmounted resulting in all kernels except 10.10 in the grub list.