# No visible screen after updating to 11.10, system boots to tty1

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, screen, tty

I have just upgraded via the update manager from 11.04 to 11.10 and have a problem in that after rebooting I have no visible screen, just an extremely thin line along the top of my monitor. As I am running on AMD64 with an Nvidia card I tried the solution outlined [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41303/system-boots-to-a-black-screen-after-upgrade-to-11-04) as regards renaming my xorg.conf file via a 11.04 live CD, but this has not worked.

According to GRUB my new updated kernel is 3.0.0-11 (Development Branch) and I must say that I was unpleasantly surprised that a distribution upgrade via the update manager on release day would upgrade me to a development release. Can anyone offer any advice as to how I can solve this problem?

EDIT - update on problem

After perusing many forum entries, entry #27 for 64-bit [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11293922#post11293922) actually worked. After "sudo reboot now" I got into the GUI and everything seemed OK. Then went to update manager and found I had 700MB plus of updates to still install. Started installing them, and while update manager was running in the background I attempted to open Firefox. The screen immediately went to a multi-coloured "sandstorm" and everything froze - neither the mouse or keyboard had any effect. All I could do was reboot by pressing the reset button, and since that the system only boots into tty1. What now?

Answer (score 1):

to solve the first problem you just need to delete the xorg.conf file 
easily this way (as root):

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

the system should generate a new one automatically if not used the default one and you probably should install your nvidia card's driver.

***always make a backup of a file before deleting it (copy contents and save with different name or tag like xorg.conf.backup .e.g) ***

for the second problem, it happens with nvidia usually if you didn't install the driver or you are using too much desktop effects while you have nvidia card

currently i believe ubuntu 11.x is unstable with nvidia cards so don't pressure it with lots of graphics , 10.X was more stable unfortunately i think i'm gonna switch back to 10

- if you need me to explain the steps of installing nvidia driver i'll be glad to help
  good luck

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 11.10 doesn't boot sometimes correctly, showing the user a black screen. I don't know how to prevent this, but I know how to get the graphical shell back when it happens.

CTRL+ALT+F1 then:

1. enter user name
2. enter password
3. `sudo restart lightdm ; exit`
4. enter password

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old question, (8+ years) Although; hopefully if someone in the future has the same problem, this may help:

Copy pasted from my own answer:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt autoremove

sudo apt remove ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

[Ubuntu boots to black screen with cursor after upgrade (from 18.04 to 20.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279976/ubuntu-boots-to-black-screen-with-cursor-after-upgrade-from-18-04-to-20-04/1279979#1279979)